# How to move an element vertically on scroll, but only in respective BS4 container

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Within a BS4 container, I have a div box. I would like this div box, along with the nested content, to scroll along while I am scrolling, however confined to the respective BS4 container. Ideally, it would stop at a predetermined height (both Y directions) within the BS4 container. [link to example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN4I8.png).

The div element that I want to move vertically upon scrolling is the id="solutions-container" inside `<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6"></div>`

Ideally, I am looking for a vanilla JS code solution, as I am still learning the ropes & knots of the business.

I'll include the relevant section of the webpage html code here. CSS will be on fiddle along with some incomplete JS because I am not sure on how to proceed.

http://jsfiddle.net/25fnba7o/1/

```
<!-- SECTION 2 --> 
<!--PRODUCTS AND SERVICES SECTION-->
<div class="products-services-container container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="product-image-container1">
              <img id="prodimg1" class="product-images prodimg1 img-fluid"src="images/Production-icons/cnc.png" alt="">
              <img id="prodimg2" class="product-images prodimg2 img-fluid" src="images/Production-icons/Sand-casting.png" alt="">
              <img id="prodimg3" class="product-images prodimg3 img-fluid"src="images/Production-icons/cnc.png" alt="">
              <img id="prodimg4" class="product-images prodimg4 img-fluid" src="images/Production-icons/Sand-casting.png" alt="">
              <img id="prodimg5" class="product-images prodimg5 img-fluid"src="images/Production-icons/cnc.png" alt="">
              <img id="prodimg6" class="product-images prodimg6 img-fluid" src="images/Production-icons/Sand-casting.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div><!--/ .col -->
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div id="solutions-container" class="solutions-container">
                <!--THE BLACK IN THE BLUE BLOCK (div)-->
                <div class="solutions-inside">
                    <h3 class="solutions-header text-left">Our Solutions</h3>
                    <h5 class="solutions-para text-left">
                        CNC Precision Machined Components Assemblies

                        High Pressure Die Castings

                        Grey & Ductile Iron Castings

                        Steel Castings

                        Investment Precision Castings

                        Aluminum Castings

                        Bronze and Brass Castings

                        Forged Components

                        Sheet Metal Components
                    </h5>
                </div><!--/ .solutions-inside -->
            </div><!--/ .solutions-container -->
        </div><!--/ .col -->
    </div><!--/ .row -->

</div><!--/ .container-fluid -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess the problem here is that I can't use the parent BS container as a sort of default position. Instead, I added the pageYoffset property as to define when I want to scroll along and when to stop. I guess I will have to twig that a bit when I change to smaller screens, but for now I am happy.

Here is the JS code and the class that I added to make things work.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    var solutionsContElement = document.getElementById("solutions-container");
    let minPosition = 1400;
    let maxPosition = 3000;

    if (window.pageYOffset > minPosition ) {
        solutionsContElement.classList.add("sticky");
    } else if (window.pageYOffset > maxPosition) {
        solutionsContElement.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
});
```

And the CSS for the class "sticky".

```
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 20vh;
}
```